# Deprecated method in two interfaces

Tags: java, deprecated

I have an interface with a deprecated method:

```
public interface A
{
    @Deprecated
    public String getUUID();
}
```

And another interface with the same but non-deprecated method:

```
public interface B
{
    public String getUUID();
}
```

A class that implements both interfaces:

```
public class MyBean implements A, B
{
    @Override
    public String getUUID()
    {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
}
```

There is a warning during the compilation of `MyBean`:

```
javac -Xlint:deprecation MyBean.java A.java B.java
MyBean.java:8: warning: [deprecation] getUUID() in A has been deprecated
    public String getUUID()
                  ^
1 warning
```

I cannot really understand why is this warning necessary when I implement `B` which defines the non-deprecated method...

Comment: Isn't that the expected behavior ? As you implement both the warning is just mentioning that the A implementation is deprecated. For me nothing is wrong with that.

Comment: Admittedly, deprecation works in a rather coarse-grained way, but the Javadoc for java.lang.Deprecated clearly states "Compilers warn when a deprecated program element is used or overridden in non-deprecated code", so this behavior is as designed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already answered your question.

You get the warning because you do `implement A`, which has the `@Deprecated` annotation. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html):

> [@Deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotation indicates that the marked element
>   is deprecated and should no longer be used. The compiler generates a
>   warning whenever a program uses a method, class, or field with the
>   @Deprecated annotation.

I don't see anything wrong with that warning. It should be there as you are really implementing a *Deprecated* method that's found in one of the interfaces you're implementing.

Comment: +1 for writing an answer with reference to the java doc, whereas I simply wrote a comment.

Comment: Ok, this looked somewhat confusing. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation you've provided satisfies both interfaces, so anything that applies to either of them applies to the implementation as well. There's no reason to single out B as the only one that applies. If you don't want A, don't implement it.